# How does the Disguise Spell feat work against counterspelling?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, spellcasting, counterspelling

If my bard with the feat **Disguise Spell** (*Complete Adventurer* 108) is the victor in the opposed check (my bard's Perform skill check against onlookers' Spot skill checks) can the spell he cast still be countered normally? Because it doesn't require a Spellcraft skill check, can the spell be countered with a [*dispel magic*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsDtoE.html#dispel-magic) spell?

---

***Note:*** I play a bard in the current campaign, and I optimized him for being a bard (Disguise Spell, Lyric Spell, Melodic Casting, Song of Heart, etc.). Through careful stacking of bonuses, his 28 Cha, a masterwork instrument, magic items, and a DM-created item, my Perform checks are d20+40 as level 17 bard.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, the disguised spell cannot be counterspelled**

From Disguise Spell:

> Onlookers must match or exceed your check result with a Spot check to detect that you’re casting a spell (your performance is obvious to everyone in the vicinity, but the fact that you are casting a spell isn’t).

From [Counterspells](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/castingSpells.htm#counterspells):

> To use a counterspell, you must select an opponent as the target of the counterspell. You do this by choosing the ready action. In doing so, you elect to wait to complete your action until your opponent tries to cast a spell.

Because one cannot detect the casting of a spell, one cannot act in response.

That said, if the effect of the spell is not instantaneous, there may be opportunity for the caster holding their action to instead dispel the effect of the spell.